# How to make normal List as ImmutableList?

Tags: java, guava, immutability

I have my below Builder pattern which is thread safe and also making sure `parameterMap` and `dataType` cannot be modified after being assigned to `InputKeys` class by using ImmutableMap and ImmutableList Guava class.

```
public final class InputKeys {

    private final long userid;
    private final long clientid;
    private final List<String> holderEntry;

    private static final ImmutableList<String> DEFAULT_TYPE = ImmutableList.of("HELLO");    

    private InputKeys(Builder builder) {
        this.userid = builder.userId;
        this.clientid = builder.clientid;
        this.holderEntry = builder.holderEntry.build();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        protected final long clientid;
        protected long userid;
        protected ImmutableList.Builder<String> holderEntry = ImmutableList.<String>builder().addAll(DEFAULT_TYPE);

        public Builder(InputKeys key) {
            this.clientid = key.clientid;
            this.userid = key.userid;
            this.holderEntry = ImmutableList.<String> builder().addAll(key.holderEntry);
        }           

        public Builder(long clientid) {
            this.clientid = clientid;
        }

        public Builder setUserId(long userid) {
            this.userid = Long.valueOf(userid);
            return this;
        }       

        public Builder addEntry(List<String> holderEntry) {
            this.holderEntry.addAll(holderEntry);
            return this;
        }           

        public InputKeys build() {
            return new InputKeys(this);
        }
    }

    // getters here
}
```

Now I have two requirements:

- If anyone is not calling `addEntry` method then my `holderEntry` list should only have  HELLO in it.
- If anyone is calling `addEntry` method with some List of String, I just want to use that List they are passing.

With my current design, let' say if anyone passes new List which has WORLD string in it then my `holderEntry` variable contains two values one is HELLO and WORLD which is wrong. In this scenario I want to have WORLD only. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave `holderEntry` empty by default in the builder?

And in the constructor of `InputKeys` you would check if the `builder.holderEntry` is empty. If so, you would set `this.holderEntry` to `DEFAULT_TYPE`. It would be more efficient and cleaner too.

In the `Builder`:

```
 protected ImmutableList.Builder<String> holderEntry = ImmutableList.<String>builder();
```

In `InputKeys` constructor:

```
List<String> holderEntry = builder.holderEntry.build();
this.holderEntry = holderEntry.isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_TYPE : holderEntry;
```

Comment: Can I not do this directly in that addEntry method? `this.holderEntry = ImmutableList.<String> builder().addAll(holderEntry);`

Comment: @user1950349 by this, you would lose the previous content of holderEntry when addEntry is called for the second, third etc. time. So calling `addEntry(Arrays.asList("BLA")); addEntry(Arrays.asList("FOO"));` would result in only FOO, not [BLA, FOO].

Comment: Can you provide an example how we can do this in constructor?

Comment: So in the constructor, we can also like this right `this.holderEntry = builder.holderEntry.build().isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_TYPE : builder.holderEntry.build(); ` and remove the first line you have in the constructor?

Comment: @user1950349 That also works, but is very inefficient, as it will copy the content of builder.holderEntry twice instead of once (you are making a copy for every build() call). If holderEntry contains many elements, there can be a huge difference, and I think it actually impairs readability instead of improving it, so I see no advantage.

Comment: Yeah that thing I agree and most of the time it will be used as `DEFAULT_TYPE` as nobody will be setting this up but max this list will have 6-7 elements in it or 10..